# Cmake error with wxWidgets installation in CodeBlocks, after build completed

Tags: c++, cmake, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I have downloaded wxWidgets 3.1.4 on Windows 10, and built it using CodeBlocks 17.12, and the GCC compiler version 5.1.0. I used CMake GUI 3.18.2.

In CMake, I used the "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" generator, with the "Use default native compilers" option. The `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` was set to `Debug`. The `wxBUILD_SHARED` option was enabled.

In CB, the build process completed successfully (at least the debug version for now). The next step was to **install** it. The process reached 100% completion, but yielded the following error:

[image]

What might be the cause of this error? I am not as comfortable with C++ and CMake. I'm coming from a .NET background.

Comment: Could you include more information like build log?

Comment: @Bruk apologies for the potentially stupid question, but where may I find the build logs? Somewhere in the same directory as the output for the build?

Comment: @Igor I have been following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfpIcU9uB_c

Comment: @Al2110, Which OS are you trying to build it on? Are you using MinGW on Windows or CygWin/gcc on Windows or native gcc on Linux?

Comment: @Igor it is on Windows 10, MinGW.

Comment: @Al2110, in this case all you do is: `cd wxWidgets\build\msw && mingw-32 -f makefile.gcc BUILD=DEBUG SHARED=0`. Keep in mind that if you will need to build any sample, all you will need is `cd wxWidgets\samples\minimal` and then enter `the same mingw` command again.

Comment: maybe you will need to use the latest version of CodeBlocks 20.03:
https://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/